# First touch press on button not triggering command in WPF (using Prism Dialog)

Tags: wpf, touch, prism

I'm trying to make a simple keypad for entering a password on a touch monitor. The first touch press on the button highlights it, but doesn't trigger the `Command`. After the first press, all buttons function normally. When I click the buttons with my mouse they also function normally, even at the first click.

[image: First press not registering]

I think it has something to do with focus and I've already set `Focusable="False"` in the `Style`, but still the first touch press focusses the button. I would like to disable the focus completely and not have the button highlighted.

My XAML code:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestShell.Dialogs.ExitApplicationDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestShell.Dialogs"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             Background="White"
             BorderThickness="2"
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TouchButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="48"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="400" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="300"/>
            <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
            <Setter Property="prism:Dialog.WindowStartupLocation" Value="CenterScreen" />
            <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
    </prism:Dialog.WindowStyle>
    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="{Binding DisplayedPasscode}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="10" FontSize="58" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="1"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="2" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="2"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="3" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="3"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="4" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="4"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="5" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="5"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Content="6" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="6"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="7" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="7"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Content="8" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="8"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Content="9" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="9"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Content="0" Style="{StaticResource TouchButton}" Command="{Binding KeyPressCommand}" CommandParameter="0"/>
        <!--<Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Content="Cancel" Margin="3" FontSize="24" Command="{Binding CancelDialogCommand}"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Content="" Margin="3" FontSize="24"/>-->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I'm using `IDialogService.ShowDialog` from the Prism library to show the keypad.

**Update 1**

I tried setting the focus on the Windows hosting the keypad `UserControl` using the following code, but it made no difference.

```cs
    public partial class ExitApplicationDialog : UserControl
    {
        public ExitApplicationDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(() => 
            {
                Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
                yourParentWindow.Activate();
                yourParentWindow.Focus();
            }));
        }
    }
```

**Update 2**

I used `Snoop` to check where the focus is before and after the first touch press. Snoop indicates that the focus both before and after the first press is on `DialogWindow`.

**Update 3**

I'm now thinking about creating a custom button that will also trigger the command on the first press. I've done a test by attaching to the `PreviewTouchDown` event.

```cs
        private int index = 0;
        private void Button_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"PreviewTouchDown {index}");
            index++;
        }
```

The strange thing is that the first time I press the button (when it is not firing the `Command`), it triggers the event only once, while every other button press triggers the event twice.

**Update 4**

The difference between touch and mouse click is that the first touch click triggers the `PreviewTouchDown` and `TouchDown` events, while every other touch click also triggers de `PreviewMouseDown` and `Click` events. With a mouse click the `PreviewMouseDown` and `Click` events are always triggered.

| First Touch Press | Following Touch Press |
| --- | --- |
| - `PreviewTouchDown` - `TouchDown` | - `PreviewTouchDown` - `TouchDown` - `PreviewMouseDown` - `Click` |

| First Mouse Click | Following Mouse Click |
| --- | --- |
| - `PreviewMouseDown` - `Click` | - `PreviewMouseDown` - `Click` |

Comment: I think the focus problem is not related to the buttons but the dialog window itself. Something causing it to lose focus and then in your first tap the dialog window gots the focus.

Comment: Update 4 is a godsend. Thank you very much for that.

Comment: @MorElmaliach Glad to hear it helped! Any change you figured out the solution to this issue also? ;)

Comment: Had the same issue, Update 4 worked, I now use Touch_Down() initially and then use Click() for handling the inputs.

Comment: Thank you @Nico for the comment. If you use TouchDown initially, does this mean that you won't be able to use the button with a mouse click? I'm looking for a solution to use the button both with mouse click and with touch.

Comment: @MrEighteen I can use both mouse and touch in my virtual keyboard. My solution is similar to yours that I use Button controls with Commands, those are automatically executed when you click them. For each button I registered the TouchDown event handler that will execute the button command in code-behind like this: private bool initiallyAcceptTouch = true;

private void Button_OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
 if (this.initiallyAcceptTouch)
 {
  this.initiallyAcceptTouch = false;
  var button = (Button)sender;
  button.Command.Execute(button.CommandParameter);
 }
}

Comment: @Nico Thank you for the code, I will implement it as well!